# need suggestions on how to setup getopt_long to properly pass command line arguments

Tags: c++, getopt, command-line-arguments

Folks,
I went over example of using get_opt_long here:  https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long_only
And I am still confuse on how to utilized in my case. I have multiple options in my case.

```
-Aa => ask for all
-As => ask for stats
-Af => ask for file
-seed => pass seed
-num => repeat times
```

I can get -seed and -num to work, but not sure how to incorporate -Ap, -Ax -Af

here is my option struct:

```
enter code here
{"seed"              , required_argument , NULL , 's'} , 
{"num"               , required_argument , NULL , 'n'} , 
{"ask_all"           , no_argument       , NULL , 'a'} , 
{"ask_stat"          , no_argument        , NULL ,  't'} , 
{NULL                , 0                 , NULL , 0}
```

also, how can I use -Ap, -As as command line argument. I am force to use unic character for all my options.

my while block has

```
case 's':
  seed = atoi(optarg);
  break;
case 'n':
  num = atoi(num);
case 'a':
  ask->all = true;   
  break;
```

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you add additional relevant tags to your question. Its rare for C++ users to use `getopt` for command line parsing, because there are other better libraries for the C++ realm

Comment: @WhiZTiM argp? Your comment hints of a plurality of options.

Comment: Can you folks suggest some options?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

1. Use long arguments for `"Aa"`, `"As"` and `"Af"`
2. Use one short argument `'A'` which takes a required argument that is the `'a'`, `'s'` or `'f'` character

Comment: problem is I want to use both "ask_all" and "Aa" as an argument. May be I can duplicate lines for them.

Comment: @Romeo Not a problem with either solution.